# JavaScript - Replace specific word index in html string

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I have a challenging mission in JS string manipulation:
There is a HTML string in which I need to replace a word at a specific word index. The word index is the number of the word when ignoring the HTML tags.

For example, here is the HTML string:

```
<span style="font-family:Times New Roman;">At times like this I don't know what to
do. Other times I have no problem.</span>
```

The  task is to replace word number 2 in the html (which is the word times) with the text: `<span style="color:red;">times</span>`

So the final HTML string should be:

```
<span style="font-family:Times New Roman;">At <span style="color:red;">times</span> 
like this I don't know what to do. Other times I have no problem.</span>
```

Any ideas for this challenge?

Comment: Do you want to replace all occurrences of that word or just the first one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first find the word by tokenizing the filtered HTML, and then do the replacement.

Let's start from your string :

```
var html = '<span style="font-family:Times New Roman;">At times like this don\'t know what to do. Other times I have no problem.</span>';
```

**Case 1, you want to replace all occurrences :**

```
var tokens = html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,'').split(/\W+/).filter(Boolean);
var newHTML = html.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+tokens[1]+'\\b', 'g'), function(s){
     return '<span style="color:red;">'+s+'</span>'
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/AnisAVI/7/)

**Case 2, you just want to replace the word at the specified index (this one is surprisingly tricky) :**

```
var tokens = html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,'').split(/\W+/).filter(Boolean);
var wordToReplaceIndex = 1, wordToReplace = tokens[wordToReplaceIndex];
var occIndex = 0;
for (var i=0; i<wordToReplaceIndex; i++) {
   if (tokens[i]===wordToReplace) occIndex++;
}
i=0;
var newHTML = html.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+wordToReplace+'\\b', 'g'), function(s){
    return (i++===occIndex) ? '<span style="color:red;">'+s+'</span>' : s
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/AnisAVI/6/)

**Alternate solution for case 2 :**

```
var i=0, wordToReplaceIndex = 1;
var newHTML = html.replace(/>([^<]+)</, function(txt) {
  return txt.replace(/\w+/g, function(s) {
    return i++==wordToReplaceIndex ? '<span style="color:red;">'+s+'</span>' : s;
  })
});
```

Can you spot why the second one was tricky ? ;)

Comment: your solutions only replaces the first occurrence, not sure if they is the requirement or not.

Comment: In the example of the question, it's the first occurrence. For replacing all occurrence, just add the `g` flag.

Comment: I get that, just making the OP aware, it could be a mistake in his/her question :)

Comment: I am still trying to understand your code, but anyway your solution in 'case 2' works great. I don't know regex well so I can't tell why it was tricky :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think a decent solution would be to split and replace then join. Here's an example:

```
<div id="replace-me">Hello, world</div>
```

---

```
replaceWordAtIndex = function (text, index, replacement) { 
    text = text.split(' ');
    text[index] = replacement;
    text = text.join(' ');
    return text;
}

wrapWordAtIndex = function (text, index, before, after) { 
    text = text.split(' ');
    text[index] = before + text[index] + after;
    text = text.join(' ');
    return text;
}

var obj = document.getElementById('replace-me');
obj.innerText = replaceWordAtIndex(obj.innerText, 1, 'Universe');
obj.innerHTML = wrapWordAtIndex(obj.innerText, 1, '<b>', '</b>');
```

---

Should result in:

```
<div id="replace-me">Hello, <b>Universe</b></div>
```

And here's a [JSFiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmaru/1) to see it in action

Answer (score 1):

```
function smartReplace(str,index,strReplace){

    var wStart=0,wEnd=0;
    var startInd=str.indexOf(">")+1;    
    var wc=0;
    for(i=startInd;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            wc=wc+1;
            if (wc==index) 
            {   
                wEnd=i-1;
                break;
            }
            wStart=i+1;
        }
    }

    var newString = str.substring(0,wStart) + strReplace + str.substring((wEnd +1),(str.length-1));
    document.write(newString);
}
```

**> call the smartReplace() like follows**

```
var str1="<span style=\"font-family:Times New Roman;\">At times like this I don't know what to do. Other times I have no problem.</span>)";
smartReplace(str1,3,"<span style=\"color:red;\">times</span>");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but I am looking for a function that can replace a specific word when the character index is unknown. For example "replace word number 2".

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '<span style="font-family:Times New Roman;">At times like this don\'t know what to do. Other times I have no problem.</span>';
var tokens = html.replace("Times","<span style="color:red;">times</span>");
```

Comment: It'd be best to explain the code rather than just dumping. It helps educate those who find the answer in future!

Answer (score 0):

ive been using this jQuery plugin to replace/edit text in any part of the DOM. quite helpful and easy to use with complete REGEX support

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/