# JavaScript/Html - Change Font Size/Color After 8 Decimal Places

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like suggestions on how to change the font/color the two last digits of a number with 10 decimal places, see below.

0.0000000012

What I would like to do is change the font/colour of only the '12' numbers to red and half the size whilst the leading 0.00000000 remains black and normal text size.

Is anyone able to provide any examples on how to do this?

Comment: You should add those last two digits in other span, to do that...

Comment: What did you try and how far did you get? Show us your code, at the very least show us how you get the number. Is it in a JavaScript variable when you begin?

Comment: In case you don't have a fixed number of decimal places (e.g. not always 10) you can use regex to find proper part of the string, then create 2 spans with different styles  for each span

Comment: Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: If you don't want to use another `span` tag or something similar, Here is a link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737776/how-to-color-specific-word-in-a-container-using-css

Answer (score 1):

In case you hard code these numbers, for example:

Your code:

`<p>0.0000000012</p>`

**Solution to your problem:**

```html
<span>0.0000000012</span>
<br />

<!-- Solution -->
<span>0.00000000</span><span style="color: red; font-size: 10px;">12</span>
```

Of course you should style with CSS - better practice. Also, take a look at [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Excellent, what about an example for the regex?

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted. Regarding `RegExp`: Stack Overflow community encourages you to first try and solve the problem by yourself, and then ask for help based on where you got stuck. Since I gave you a working solution already, **it is for your own benefit to try to solve this problem yourself** in a different way - using `RegExp`. There are many examples provided in the link above as well as other Internet resources.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will dynamically highlight a number after dot ".", which is not equal to 0;

```
<p id="number">0.0000000012</p>

<script>
  var el = document.getElementById('number').innerText;
  var a = el.split('.');
  var x = '';
  var y = '';

  for(var i=0; i<a[1].length; ++i)  {
    if(a[1][i] == 0)
      x = x + a[1][i];
    else
      y = y + a[1][i];
  }

  var n = a[0]+'.'+x+'<span style="color:red;">'+y+'</span>';

  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = n;
</script>
```

Comment: I was actually after the last two digits. Not digits that don't have 0's

Comment: @daygle you change condition!

Comment: No I didn't, I said the last two digits in my first comment.

Comment: I meant you can change condition that will suit your needs! @daygle